# Academic hugo theme gives error on blox-bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5, hugo, academic-graph

I encountered an error while constructing a website with [the hugo academic theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/theme-academic-cv/). This error is accurate as there is no blox-bootstrap/v5 present in the modules.

```
Error: failed to load modules: module "github.com/HugoBlox/hugo-blox-builder/modules/blox-bootstrap/v5" not found in "C:\\Hugo\\meet\\themes\\github.com\\HugoBlox\\hugo-blox-builder\\modules\\blox-bootstrap\\v5"; either add it as a Hugo Module or store it in "C:\\Hugo\\meet\\themes".: module does not exist
```

THe *blox-bootstap/v5* is mentioned required in *go.mod* file. The academic theme is the only one causing errors on both Windows and Ubuntu, while other themes function without any issues.

I do not know how to resolve the issue and make it functional

Answer (score 0):

The theme is made by George Cushen. You should ask him. Note that he seems to have abandoned it, because it is not updated in 10 years, the Discord link does not work and the other links all point to his Hugo Blox website. George has more recent themes that are clearly better maintained.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent release requires hugo 0.123.3 to build. But I still have a hard time migrating my own website from wowchemy to hugo blox.